# Laravel pagination in Data Table

Tags: laravel

I am using DataTable plugin in Laravel. I have a record of 3000 entries in some
But when i load that page it loads all 3000 records in the browser then create pagination, this slow down the page loading.

How to fix this or correct way

Answer (score 0):

Use server-side processing. 
Get help from some Laravel Packages. Such as Yajra's: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can solve pagination either on the front end, the back end (server or database side), or a combination of both.

Server side processing, without a package, would mean setting up TOP/FETCH or make rows in data being returned from your server.   You could also load a small amount (say 20) and then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, load another 20 or so. I mention the inclusion of front end processing as well because I’m not sure what your use cases are, but I imagine it’s pretty rare any given user actually needs to see 3000 rows at a time.

Given that Data Tables seems to have built-in functionality for paginating data, I think that @tersakyan is essentially correct — what you want is some form of back-end filtering or paginating of rows of data to limit what’s being sent to the front end.  I don’t know if that package works for you or not or what your setup looks like, but pagination can also be achieved directly from a DataBase returning data via the SQL (using TOP/FETCH for example) or could be implemented in a Controller or Service by tracking pages of data and “loading a page at a time” both from the server and then into the table. All you would need is a unique key to associate each "set of pages" for a specific request.

But for performance, you want to avoid both large data requests and operations on large sets of data. So the more you limit how much data is being grabbed or processed at any stage of your application using it, the more performant your application will be in principle.